# Answer a bad question if it's gotten a terrible answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

Say you stumble upon a question that's written poorly. For example, the intent of the question is clear, but the OP doesn't mention anything he's tried.
The question has an (upvoted) answer already, but the code in that answer is, whatever the reason, *bad*.

*Should you answer the question in an attempt to educate both the OP and the bad answerer?*
(After obvious actions like editing the question, downvoting / flagging where necessary)

The reason for this meta post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400376/

The question's intent seems clear to me, but the answer that's been posted is terribly inefficient.
Did I do the right thing by answering with an (imo) better solution, and explaining my downvote? Or should I just have left the question to be?

Comment: When I see a low quality question without any effort I would rather skip it. If the answer is even of a lower quality I get an instant headache.

Comment: To me, the problem is that those bad answers result in bad programmers that might answer with more bad answers, eventually. Knowing I could write up a good answer to the question in a few minutes makes it pretty tempting not to just let it be...

Comment: @Cerbrus seems like a good reason to closevote and downvote the question so that it can be deleted; and _not_ answer with a good answer which will be upvoted and _prevents_ automatic deletion.

Comment: @l4mpi: The bad answer was upvoted, though. wouldn't that prevent automated deletion?

Comment: Only if the answer score is >0. For bad answers that have only received a few upvotes, this is usually fixable by downvoting and leaving a comment informing future readers why the answer is bad.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. Thanks for the feedback, @l4mpi!

Comment: Don't forget to edit the question as much as possible, too.

Comment: _"bad answers result in bad programmers"_ Isn't downvoting the bad answer with a reasonably explanatory comment enough of a sign to the OP that the answer should not be put into practice? If OP still ignores that sign, sorry but he is already a bad person/programmer.

Comment: Bad answers on StackOverflow don't result in bad programmers; if they blindly trust answers on StackOverflow, they were bad programmers to begin with.

Comment: Good point, @AirThomas. I didn't look at it that way, yet.

Comment: This is my LART. There are many like it, but this one is mine.  My LART is my best friend. It is my life. I must master it as I must master my life.  ... fire down votes, flags, and/or close votes as appropriate and move on.

Comment: If you have an answer, you are welcome to answering; also, if you can, you are able to improve the question itself. At the end, you are helping the community.

Comment: Is there a reason why the answer to this would not be, "Yes, answer the question"?

Comment: I have seen many questions of questionable (not bad) quality receive terrible answers. The asker typically accepts the first answer they get that makes their code "work" - I don't think they even read newer, better answers. Posting a comment on an answer explaining why it is bad also leads to flames, in my experience.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do onto the question as the question deserves, and unto the answer as the answer deserves. That is, a bad answer should be downvoted, commented upon, and possibly flagged. A bad question should be edited, commented upon (to help the OP write a good question), ignored, or closed.

I realize it may seem unconstructive to point out flaws of an answer without providing a better one, but if OP failed to ask a constructive question, why should we write a constructive answer? Also, why should people strive to ask good questions if they get good answers anyway?

Comment: I feel this answer explains _why_ not to answer a little better than vba's. Accepted.

Answer (score 10):

The circumstances surrounding a bad, terrible, poor question shouldn't have any influence on your action(s) which should be downvoting the question, possibly voting to close and moving on...

If you spot an answer that in your opinion is wrong, just downvote if you know it's wrong and move on but please:

Don't answer those questions...

Comment: even if you do answer, be aware, at some point in time 5 people like me will come across that poor question and vote to close following voting to delete -- all your effort may be deleted and the rep gone too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You did the *right* thing. The fact that the question is bad shouldn't stop you from sharing what you know.

PS : You actually took time to explain your down-vote, good. Most down-votes go unexplained. :P

Comment: "The fact that the question is bad shouldn't stop you from sharing what you know." So many things wrong with that, I don't even know where to start... Imagine the exact same question would be asked by a colleague at your workplace, who's asking similar questions multiple times an hour, without any effort from them. Would you happily answer their questions day after day? I don't think so.

Comment: @l4mpi - What if it is kind of a Regex question in which the OP has not shown any effort?. But you know your answer could help a hapless soul looking for the same thing.

Comment: @TheLostMind If the OP was really intrested in Regex he would Google for it to truly understand every part of it(that's at least what I would do).

Comment: So you teach both the OP and the future hapless visitor that SO is a dumping ground for awful questions and they should ask more of them! Yay! We get one step closer to being worse than Yahoo Answers!

Comment: @Wooble Agree with your point, but let's be honest...we could *never* be worse than Yahoo Answers.

Comment: @Wooble SE has atension between being a repository of knowledge and a place to help people. If we want to be a knowledge almost all regex questions on the site aren't valid because they would all be answered by a basic tutorial on regex. Why means what kind of regex questions _actually_ belong here?

Comment: The right thing to do is to clean up the crap. Downvote it, vote to close it, flag it. The same applies to any answer.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - If we clean /close all *bad* questions, then people with similar problems will have no option but to post more number of such questions on SO. Why??, because they don't understand something and they didn't find what the were looking for.

Comment: @TheLostMind I think it is important to remember it is not the subject matter of the question which makes it bad, it is the composition of the question. If we clean up the poorly composed questions it establishes a higher standard of question which hopefully future askers of questions on the same subject matter will live up to.

Comment: @Simon1979 has answered it for me.

Comment: +1 To me, this community is about sharing knowledge, and if possible helping others to improve.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif